# grep fails to find escaped dash that used to work

Tags: linux, unix, grep, centos7, centos5

I have specific strings that are followed by either a dash '-', vertical bar '|' or digit

8-year-old code has always filtered the data with [-\|0-9]

this grep is now failing

```
> cat regex
^abc[\-\|0-9]
> echo abc- | grep -v -f regex
abc-
```

It works fine when the backslash is removed

```
> cat regex
^abc[-\|0-9]
> echo abc- | grep -v -f regex
>
```

The backslash works fine on the command-line!

```
> echo abc- | grep -v ^abc[\-\|0-9]
>
```

Since this works directly on the command-line it would seem to be a change in how "-f" loads the file into the program?

I have validated this behavior on both GNU grep 2.20 (on CentOS7) & GNU grep 2.5.1 (on CentOS5)

The obvious solution is to just remove the backslash. Every indication from my searching says the backslash should be allowed.

I would really like to understand why it started failing...but works fine on the command-line. I no longer have access to older linux boxes to test on.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it ever worked, it may have been a bug. In POSIX BRE, [a backslash in ranged expressions is not special](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03):

> `<backslash>` shall be special except when used in a bracket expression

Alternatively, since your regex range actually means "all characters between `\` and `\`, plus pipes and numbers", you may have been using a locale that considered `-` equivalent to `\` in collation order. I wasn't able to reproduce this with any locales on my systems.

> but works fine on the command-line

It doesn't. Since you're not quoting the string, the shell removes the backslashes. Here's what `grep` ends up seeing:

```
$ printf '%s\n' ^abc[\-\|0-9]
^abc[-|0-9]
```